# Preview XML Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I was using Eclipse for build android application. I have switched now Android Studio for development. I have issue in Layout Edit. I have folder called Layout, Layout-large etc. In eclipse during layout edit, eclipse show preview of it as per suitable device screen. In Android Studio it's not switching automatic device screen as per layout folder. I have need all time manually switch device screen from drop down. I am using Android Studio 2.2.2. Anyone can please suggest me to solve my issue ?

**Example**
If I have layout folder called layout-sw360dp and layout-sw480dp and mainActivity.xml in both folder when I preview this xml, I need to choose device manually its not showing automatic device as per layout folder.

[image]

**Thanks**

Comment: It is not clear what you are expecting android studio to do. How are you expecting it to understand what layout to show, without telling it. If you expand the file in the project explorer, it should show both layouts, just select the one you wish to edit..

Comment: If you have two layouts, one for portrait orientation and another for landscape, if you switch orientation in the preview window, Android Studio automatically shows the other layout representing current orientation.

Comment: Hi ! I am not asking for change layout mode...if I have layout folder called layout-sw360dp and layout-sw480dp and mainActivity.xml in both folder when I preview this xml, I need to choose device manually its not showing automatic device as per layout folder. Thanks

Comment: The update with picture makes more sense now. From playing aroudn with it, it seems to open the last device i used, or a default. It does tell me which devices are valid, and which use a different layout. However it does not default to one that is valid. And unfortunately I dont know of any way to fix this,, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the option to preview all screen sizes was removed in Android Studio 2.2 :-(

It was replaced by another, more powerful option - **the bottom right corner of the preview can now be dragged, making the layout re-scale in real time**. It also shows where you should drag to for each device size.

This is not the best solution, but it gets quite convenient once you get used to it :-)

[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean... I don't think this was ever a feature in Android Studio, sorry :(